# Google Analytics is double counting - how can I use Firebug to see *where* the cookie change is occuring?

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, firebug

I have managed to really determine that GA is double-counting my website. First by checking the cookies that it creates in my browser and seeing that just going to the homepage marks it as having visited 2 pages, another marks it as 4 pages, etc. But I also can see in GA that there are some people that have page depth of 1, 3, 5, etc. Confusing.

But using this site I saw that I can use Firebug, which I did, and I set the console to show me whenever cookies are edited. It is clearly, on one page load, editing utmb 3 times (the second time seems to not actually change the value, the first and third time increase the value of the pages visited so it ends up showing me that 2 pages were visited). Now that I know that is happening, can I use Firebug to find out *where* in the code it is causing these cookies to be edited? I can't figure that part out. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, even when you enable logging of cookie events (in the menu of the Console tab) the line is not properly linked, like it is with other events. Maybe this will be fixed some day.

However, you can halt Javascript execution and go to the appropriate line in the debugger by using the "Halt on cookie change" button:

[image: Halt on cookie change button]

You can also limit this to a single cookie by setting a cookie breakpoint:

[image: Cookie breakpoint]